# How to find all real estate listings data?

Tags: database, api

I wonder how websites like redfin or zillow gets all the real estate listings and open house information. Is there any open data source or API to get all those?

Comment: A short amount of research would point you in the direction of several databases that have this information. See my answer for one.

Answer (score 4):

[MLS](http://www.mls.com/) gives real estate listings for various parts of the United States. And there's a [real estate cloud api](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/real-estate-cloud-mls) to access its data.

Comment: It looks like the Real Estate Cloud site unfortunately isn't up anymore. For anyone else hitting this question, [SimplyRETS](https://simplyrets.com) also provides a simple API to access real estate data from MLS's.